How can I run ObserveEvent before Observe?
I have some pickerInputs that update depending on the previous inputs within observeEvents. Besides that, I have some functions that run within a observe. I get an error because when I update the table picker then observe is ran together with a column input, which does not exist for that dataset. What is the way to make this work?
In the example below, if I change from mtcars to iris, it will print an error.
library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  pickerInput("dataset", "dataset", c("mtcars", "iris")),
  pickerInput("columns", "columns", c()),
  actionBttn("Button", "Select")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$dataset, {
    
    req(input$dataset)
    choices <- names(get(input$dataset))
    
    updatePickerInput(session = session,
                      inputId = "columns",
                      choices = choices)
    
    
  })
  
  observe({
    
    req(input$dataset)
    req(input$columns)
    
    print(input$dataset)
    print(input$columns)
    
    if(!any(input$columns == names(get(input$dataset)))) print("Error")
    
  })
  

  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


Look at the priority parameter of observe and observeEvent. Observers with higher priority will be run first

I've tried that but it's not the issue and if you pop print("OE") in the observeEvent you'll see that it is already running first. The issue is that the updatePickerInput isn't updating the input before the observe runs.

We can use freezeReactiveValue to avoid unnecessary triggering of downstream dependencies:
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(datasets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput("selected_dataset", "selected_dataset", c("mtcars", "iris")),
  pickerInput("selected_columns", "selected_columns", names(mtcars)),
  actionBttn("Button", "Select")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dataset <- reactive({
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "selected_columns")
    updatePickerInput(session = session,
                      inputId = "selected_columns",
                      choices = names(get(input$selected_dataset)))
    return(get(input$selected_dataset))
  })
  observeEvent(dataset(), {
    if(!any(input$selected_columns == names(dataset()))) {print("Error")}
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

This by the way often is good practice when using updateXXX functions.
PS: Instead of switching to observeEvent we could also use bindEvent:
  observe({
    if(!any(input$selected_columns == names(dataset()))) {print("Error")}
  }) |> bindEvent(dataset())


yours looks like the better answer. I'm confused re isolate() (see my alternative answer below, which works in this case, but is probably not the right way to go, given the availability of freezeReactiveValue. Might you help me understand, with a quick comment?

You can isolate input$dataset:
  observe({
    req(input$columns)
    if(!any(input$columns == names(get(isolate(input$dataset))))) print("Error")
    else print("OK")
  })



With isolate you can avoid taking a dependency on that input entirely. freezeReactiveValue in this case has the advantage that it fixes the behaviour (combination of dataset and columns wich does not exist) for all downstream dependencies.

This solves the MRE (like adding req(input$columns %in% names(get(input$dataset))) does), but doesn't deal with the observe() being triggered before the updated input is available and in a real application you'd still get the undesirable behaviour
